# Kivy widget alignment issue in layout

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Just started getting into Kivy, facing some alignment issue.

Please have a look on the image below, I am trying to adjust button **weather icon** marked in red circle at the location where it is marked with blue circle.

Here is the *.kv file code :

```
BoxLayout:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'horizontal'
            StackLayout:
                orientation:'tb-rl'
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: [.3, .320, .380]
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                Button:
                    id:current_temperature
                    text: root.display_current_temperature()
                    font_size:40
                    size_hint: [None, None]
                    size:[200,50]
                Button:
                    id:current_location
                    text: root.display_location()
                    font_size:15
                    size_hint: [None, None]
                    size:[200,50]
            Button:
                id:test
                text: 'weather icon'
                size_hint: [None, None]
                size:[100,100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is making use of the kivy.uix.AnchorLayout

Docs: [AnchorLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html?highlight=anchored%20layout)

```py
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'horizontal'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: [.8, 1]
        orientation:'horizontal'
        StackLayout:
            orientation:'tb-rl'
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: [.3, .320, .380]
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Button:
                id:current_temperature
                text: root.display_current_temperature()
                font_size:40
                size_hint: [None, None]
                size:[200,50]
            Button:
                id:current_location
                text: root.display_location()
                font_size:15
                size_hint: [None, None]
                size:[200,50]
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint:[.2, 1]
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'center'
            anchor_y: 'top'
            Button:
                id:test
                text: 'weather icon'
                size_hint: [1, None]
```

Please note that i have changed the size of the last Button Widget from a absolute one to a relative one. This will prevent unexpected behavior on rendering the app on different screen sizes.

Also changed the sizes of the main 2 BoxLayout Widgets to a relative one also, for the same reason as above.

Another way is adding a position hint to the Button Widget

Docs: [pos_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=pos_hint#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint)

```py
Button:
    pos_hint: {'y': 1-1/(self.parent.height/self.height)}
    id:test
    text: 'weather icon'
    size_hint: [None, None]
    size:[100,100]
```